# How would you turn these English sentences into predicate logic?

Tags: logic, predicate, language-translation, predicates

The sentences are:

Real number i is the largest real solution of the equation f.i = i + l.

No integer is larger than all others.

I feel like the first one is a for all statement, but I have no idea about the second one, at all.

Any help would be great, thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Real number i is the largest real solution of the equation f.i = i + l

[image: (i \in \mathbb{R} \land f.i = i + l) \implies (\forall k \in \mathbb{R}: ((f.k = k + l) \implies k \leq i))]

> No integer is larger than all others.

[image: \neg(\exists i \in \mathbb{Z}. \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}. i \geq k)]